# Having trouble in installing ampicc or charmc compiler

Tags: charm++

I'm not able to install the charm++ compiler (known as - charmc) or ampi compiler(ampicc) in Ubuntu:14.04, 64-bit machine so that I can run any charm++ program globally.

How can I install it?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Please provide more information so that we can help you.

Comment: I haven't installed the very basic version of it yet. I use "make" command whenever to compile/run the charm++ program, only after going to that directory. I want the very basic step of installing charmc and ampicc compiler. By the way here is the glimpse while I run charmc command :

Comment: sysadmin@user:~/Documents/charm-6.7.1/examples/charm++/hello$ charmc hello.ci
No command 'charmc' found, did you mean:
 Command 'charm' from package 'charm-tools' (universe)
charmc: command not found
sysadmin@user:~/Documents/charm-6.7.1/examples/charm++/hello$ charmc -c hello.C
No command 'charmc' found, did you mean:
 Command 'charm' from package 'charm-tools' (universe)
charmc: command not found

Comment: To run a simple hello program in charm++, I'm running following commands :

Comment: compiling : charmc hello.ci & charmc -c hello.C and charmc -o hello hello.o                          Running :

Comment: I just want the very basic step of installing the charmc and ampicc compiler globally in the system so that I can run any charm++ program written in anywhere.                                                                                       Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To build Charm++ and AMPI, you can follow the download instructions here:

https://charm.cs.illinois.edu/download/

Then build Charm++ and AMPI on Ubuntu Linux x86_64:

```
$ cd charm/
$ ./build AMPI netlrts-linux-x86_64
```

That will build charmc and ampicc in the directory netlrts-linux-x86_64/bin/.

You can then test your Charm++ installation by doing:

```
$ cd examples/charm++/hello/1darray/
$ make test TESTOPTS=++local
```

And to test an AMPI program:

```
$ cd examples/ampi/creduce/
$ make test TESTOPTS=++local
```

If the above does not work, please post the output of the build command you used.